# Long try statements

Tags: java, exception, variables, try-catch

Is there any drawback to putting most of your code for your function in a `try statement`. If I do something that requires a `try statement`, I usually end up doing a lot of work for that function inside the try statement because I usually declare my variables in there and can't use them outside that scope if I do that. Is this common and accepted? Do people usually declare variable before without initializing them so they're not doing everything (including calls to other functions) inside a `try statement`? Or does it not matter if it's very long?

Comment: Not sure what you are doing, but you can initialize a variable to some default value outside the try block.

Comment: If it annoys you, you could always add a `throws` clause to your method header and wrap only the method call in a `try/catch`-block.

Comment: @nhahtdh Or not initialise at all: `int whatever;` is valid in Java.

Comment: @11684 That's not going to be good idea in all cases.

Comment: Checked exception is what annoys me in Java, but it's really helpful

Comment: One tactic is to catch the checked exception and immediately re-throw an unchecked version. This means error handling is dealt with elsewhere and stops the 'infection' of 'throws' everywhere.

Comment: @RohitJain The OP already declares them inside the `try/catch`-block, he/she could safely just remove the type from that statement and declare the variable outside it.

Comment: @11684. Well, I was talking about your first comment. And as for your 2nd comment, if you don't initialize the varaible outside the try block, you can't use it after the try-catch block. Try it out.

Comment: It is the common practice to declare the variables that you going to use within try block outside before try block starts. And initializing the variables to default or any value.. It is done so that if those variables pointing to some I/O streams they could be closed within finally block , no matter if try fails or not.

Comment: @11684: Exception should be handled where it is most convenient. `throws` means that you are going to delegate the task of handling the Exception away to the caller - which may not make sense in all cases.

Comment: That was my point. @RohitJain

Comment: @nhahtdh I didn't say I do not agree with your suggestion, I only offered an alternative. We do not have the OP's complete source code, so we can't know what makes sense or not.

Comment: This question is in everyone's mind, sadly people just rap the entire method into a `try catch(Exception e)`. A bunch of lazy creeps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A method should do one thing and do it good. In this case your method is doing two things: business logic and error handling:

```
public Foo bar() {
    try {
        //business logic that may throw
        //...
        //end even more
    } catch(BuzzException e) {
        //Error handling
    }
}
```

Very often I find myself extracting the contents of `try` block into a separate method without error handling:

```
public Foo bar() {
    try {
        return unsafeBar();
    } catch(BuzzException e) {
        //Error handling
    }
}

public Foo unsafeBar() throws BuzzException {
    //business logic that may throw
    //...
    //end even more
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It matters if it's very long, but not for the reason you think. It matters because it makes your code hard to read and test. You'd better refactor it to several methods:

```
public void doComplexThing() {
    try {
        SomeObject o1 = doSomethingLessComplex();
        SomeOtherObject o2 = doSomethingElse(o1);
        doFinalThing(o2);
    }
    catch (SomeException e) {
        // handle the exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If a `try` block is getting a little long, it's a good idea to isolate the calls that are actually throwing the exceptions into their own methods. That way you are individually addressing what may be several kinds of exceptions being thrown in that block.

Covering many exceptions in a `try` with a plain old `catch(Exception ex)` is going to cause headaches later if you're trying to test or find a "mysterious" bug. This is not to mention things like proper resource/stream handling which is what many checked exceptions are there for.

Answer (score 0):

As a senior programmer, I understand the confusion between using a try catch perfectly over the statements that are throwing the exception vs code neatness.

Here I would lean towards `try catch over the statements that need it`.

First lets understand the need of a try catch. We catch exceptions since we want to handle it right here and right now. If we dont we throw it to the caller. We throw it so that we dont forget to handle it later. Never, `Oh!, let me finish this method and then I will worry about the exception handling later`. Do it while you code, think, do you need to print a error and return null, or do you need the user to know that something screwed up ? Do you want to consolidate all connection issues to `recycle the connection` kinda message ? If yes, then throw to your own custom exception. But be sure to handle it. Ignoring and doing bad exception handling is the root cause of increased costs of projects maintenance and customer heart burn. It is the difference between a good product and a sloppy product.

As for code neatness, I have found that comments in catch blocks make it all worth your while. Yes, there will be someone senior to you who will not understand the importance of catching the exact statement, and will catch `catch (Exception e)` directly. Pathetic, I would say. But you should stick to your ethics when you code. Do it right and do it ONCE.